# How to compare two date ranges in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I am currently trying to figure out how to compare the two date ranges using Calendar object in java.

For example, if the first two given dates are `2021-7-1 and 2021-7-8` and the second two given dates are `2021-7-8 and 2021-7-10`, it should return false because the date ranges of the first two given dates and the second two given dates are overwritten at `2021-7-8`.

Is there any possibility to figure out this using Calendar and Date objects?

Comment: Clarify what you mean *exactly* by "false" because the two ranges share the 8th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateRange a = LocalDateRange.ofClosed(
    LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-01" ) ,
    LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" )
)
.abuts(                                            // Or .overlaps or .isConnected
    LocalDateRange b = LocalDateRange.ofClosed(
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-10" )
    )
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

> using Calendar object

Never use `Calendar` or `Date`. These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Date ranges

> if the first two given dates are 2021-7-1 and 2021-7-8 and the second two given dates are 2021-7-8 and 2021-7-10, it should return false because the date ranges of the first two given dates and the second two given dates are overwritten at 2021-7-8.

You want to compare two date ranges.

### `LocalDate`

In modern Java we use `LocalDate` to represent a date without a time-of-day and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

### `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange`

To work with date ranges (a pair of `LocalDate` objects), I suggest you add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project, free-of-cost and open-source. This library includes the [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class, just what you need.

### Half-open spans

You should know that in date-time handling, it usually makes sense to define a span of time as Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a full day starts at the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *next* day.

In your case, your first range ends on the 8th, and the second range begins on the 8th. By Half-Open rules, these two ranges would [abut](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#abuts(org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange)) rather than [overlap](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#overlaps(org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange)).

```java
LocalDateRange x = LocalDateRange.of(
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-01" ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" )
);
LocalDateRange y = LocalDateRange.of(
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-10" )
);

boolean abuts = x.abuts( y );
boolean overlaps = x.overlaps( y );
```

When run.

> abuts = true
>
> overlaps = false

I believe making consistent use of Half-Open makes your code easier to read and reason about, and is less likely to have mistakes from an oversight.

### Fully-closed spans

However, if you insist on the Fully-Closed approach, the `LocalDateRange` class lets you work that way. Use [`LocalDateRange.ofClosed`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#ofClosed(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)) rather than [`LocalDateRange.of`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#of(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)).

```java
LocalDateRange a = LocalDateRange.ofClosed(
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-01" ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" )
);
LocalDateRange b = LocalDateRange.ofClosed(
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-08" ) ,
        LocalDate.parse( "2021-07-10" )
);

boolean abuts = a.abuts( b );
boolean overlaps = a.overlaps( b );
```

When run.

> abuts = false
>
> overlaps = true

Using the Fully-Closed approach, your two ranges overlap rather than abut, the opposite of what we saw above in previous example code.

### Overlaps *or* abuts

Be aware of the [`isConnected`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#isConnected(org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange)) method, the equivalent to `(overlaps(other) || abuts(other))`. The `LocalDateRange` class offers other comparison methods too.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Nice answer, Developer can use only the LocalDateRange class rather than using the whole library.